# how to prefill input form in html and make it editable

Tags: html, reactjs, input, edit

I would like to make edit page in my react app but I am struggling how to display value in input form and make it editable. I am getting Recipe data via API and would like to display it to the user, make it editable and send it again with POST request.

If I write:

```
<input
 type="text"           
 required
value={recipe.title}
onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}>
</input>
```

the title is displayed but cannot be changed in any way

if I write

```
<textarea
type="text"
required value={title}
onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}>
{recipe.title}
</textarea>
```

nothing is displayed

I suppose the ideal solution is to fetch the data and use it as initial state for useState like this:

```
const { data: recipe2 }  = useFetch(url_recipes + `${id}`)

const [title, setTitle] = useState(recipe.title);

<input
type="text"
required
value={title}
onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
></input>
```

but I am not sure how to do it exactly. Thanks for any help.

Comment: useState is not working?where you got recipe it recipe2 right?You can also use useRef for the same purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed in your last solution the ideal way is to create a double-way binding with the input and the state (by creating a controlled component). And you do that by giving as **value** the name of the state and as an **onChange** handler the correct setState method to update the value of the state. The input will be this one:

```
<input
type="text"
required
value={title}
onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
></input>
```

However to make sure the input gets the fetched data as value what you can do is using a useEffect hook to make sure the state gets the data once it has been fetched from the API:

```
const { data: recipe2 }  = useFetch(url_recipes + `${id}`)

const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
 if(recipe2 && recipe2.title){
  setTitle(recipe2.title);
 }
}, [recipe2])
```